# vim looks like solorized in tmux

Tags: linux, tmux, elementaryos

Running elementary OS. Not sure what I have misconfigured. I started tmux like `tmux -2` . Any thoughts on what it could be?

[image]

When I do `echo $TERM` I get `xterm-256color`

Comment: So I installed gnome-terminal and it works just fine. So it seems to be an issue with Elementary own terminal Pantheon

Comment: You should make your comment an answer and accept it. Read [this](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski that is not an answer that was just stating that it seemed to be something with the default terminal

Comment: OK, I understand now. In this case consider editing your question and putting this information there as a research you have done. Not everybody reads comments, the question body is more important.